# How do I make Grep less Greedy with a shell variable?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, regex-greedy

I have been polishing up my grep skills with a particular problem I have found. Basically it goes like this. I have a local file with words from a dictionary. The user will pass in a word and the script will find all words that can be made with letters from that word. The catch is, the words must be at least 4 characters long and you can only use as many letters as the user passes in. So if I passed in a word like "College" clee and cell would be acceptable words but not words like cocco because yes it contains letters from the word but college only has 1 o and 1 c. Here is my regular expression thus far.

```
egrep -i "^[("$text")]{4,}$" /usr/dict/words
```

This will find strings that contain these letters that are at least four characters long however grep is being greedy and grabbing more characters than those in the variable. How would I specify to only use the amount of characters in the variable? I've been stuck on this for a few days now to no avail. Thank you for your help and time community!

Comment: Regular expressions don't capture a notion of which letters have already been used for a match.

Comment: Would I have to pipe a grep command to it? Im sorry if this all seems stupid, I am just new to Unix and I really want to get this script to work.

Comment: No; this just isn't a task which regular expressions can be used to solve. Suppose your regular expression was simply `^[ab]{1,}`. This says to match 1 or more characters, each of which is an "a" or a "b".  There is no way with a regular expression to say that once an "a" is matched, the next character cannot be an "a".

Comment: Oh no what I am saying is if i search say college and it comes up with clee thats okay because there is a 1 c 2 l's and an e in college but it can't return words like cleeclee because granted all those letters can be found in the word college but there isn't 4 e's only 1. Does that make sense? I was told by one of my professors here that it can be down with what I have. However, if you are positive I can't even if I pipe another grep or different command, then I will ask him again. The only hint he gave me was with something like {$text:0:1} for first character and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @chepner said in the comments, regular expressions won't test for the exact number of characters that is in a range. In other words, `[ee]` will not match 2 `e`'s it will only match if there is an e at all, so `[ee]` is a redundant of `[e]`. Regular expressions usually match 1 or more of a match expression `[e]+` would match at least 1 `e` up to the buffer size of the string. To match a specific number of `e`'s you'd have to know that before hand to do something like `[e]{2,5}` which would match at least 2 but no more than 5 `e`'s.

Even if you set a pre-processor to calculate the number of letters that are repeated in the input, you'd have a hard time matching the regular expression how you think it matches. To go with your example of "college", preprocessed would look like c=1,o=1,l=2, e=2,g=1. If you were to put it in a regular expression like you had ^c?o?l{0,2}e{0,2}g?$` [note a "?" in this context is short hand for {0,1}] would not even match "college" as the match would be positional it would match "colleg", "colleeg", "colleg", etc.

To verify the length of the string what you have only verifies that there are at least for letters in the range `[]`.  You may want to change it to `grep "^.{4,}$"` to check whether the entire length is at least 4 characters.

If you aren't limited to only using grep, but are limited to bash, you may be able to use the below script to solve you're problem:

```sh
read input
cat /usr/dictwords | while read line
do
  if $(echo $line | grep "^.\{4,\}\$" >> /dev/null)
  then
    testVal=$line
    for i in $(echo $input | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g')
      testVal=$(echo "$testVal" | sed -e "s/$i/_/i")
    done
  fi
  if $(echo $testVal | grep "^_\+$" >> /dev/null)
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done
```